# Intellij Idea - Extract Class

Tags: intellij-idea

Is possible in Intellij Idea 14 do something like in Eclipse: Refactor : Extract Class?
Or I should do it manually?

Not found proper option in menu, and I am startled option is not available.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anything that's worth doing in eclipse can be done faster and easier in IntelliJ, but if you're used to eclipse then you'll have to work a little bit to understand IntelliJ's way of doing things.

If you place your cursor somewhere in the java code in question (or on the class name in the project window), the `Refactor` menu will have an `Extract` option. Extract `Delegate`, `Interface`, and `Superclass` are the three options that deal directly with classes. These menu options aren't available if your cursor isn't in java class code.

The `Interface` option extracts an interface, renames your class and makes it implement the interface. The 'Superclass' option extracts a superclass and changes references to refer to it rather than your, now, derived class. The `Delegate` option simply extracts the methods and properties you choose into a new class.

Comment: Could you please help me in this related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55835505/intellij-idea-refactoring-how-do-i-make-multiple-classes-extend-a-base-class ?

Answer (score 9):

Place your cursor onto the name of your inner class and press <kbd>F6</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

The refactoring you are looking for is probably [extract delegate](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/extract-delegate.html).