# Intellij Idea Refactoring - How do I make multiple classes extend a base class?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have 10 Java classes which have the same fields and same constructor to initialize those fields. I wanted the duplicated code to be extracted into a super class and then all the 10 classes should extend that super class. I want to do this refactoring with Intellij Idea.

I was able to extract the desired code from one of the 10 classes into a super class called BaseClass by using Refactor > Extract > Superclass. Now, I want to use Intellij to automatically make the remaining 9 classes extend BaseClass. How do I do that ?

Comment: There isn't a tool that does this directly -- @Peter is correct and I've voted up his answer on that basis. It's worth noting though, that you should only use inheritance where you have a need for polymorphism -- research Liskov's Substitution Principle to understand why. Also, subclassing is very hard and usually not needed. When you get to 10 subclasses, you have to start questioning your design (not that it's always wrong, just that large numbers of subclasses are a red-flag item that needs careful review). Checkout code-review stack overflow.

Comment: I can think of many cases where 10 subclasses is a reasonable design. In most cases the parent class will be abstract, in which case Liskov does not really apply; instances of the subclass are not substitutable for instances of the parent class because there are no such instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such refactoring.

The [find duplicates and replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/find-and-replace-code-duplicates.html) refactoring won't help you either.

I think, you have to do this manually.

Comment: As Peter correctly mentioned there is no ready tool for such a refactoring in IDEA, please follow the feature request created: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211646

Comment: @OlgaKlisho - Thank you, chenqui and хорошего дня.